# Not understanding some composition aspects (not composition)

Tags: python, duck-typing

I am brushing up on some data structures and algorithms with Python, so I am implementing an Unordered Linked list. Within the same file I first wrote a Node class followed by a List class. What I don't get is how the "current" variable in my search_item() method seems to be a node object or at least able to access the Node class methods and attributes. I noticed that if I comment out my add_node() method then "current" no longer has access to Node's methods. Now I am not explicitly using neither inheritance nor composition, so I am having a hard time seeing how current just gets to call get_next() the way the code is written below. I would think I'd have to declare current as: current = Node(self.head) but just current = self.head seems to work?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_data(self, d):
        self.data = d

    def get_next(self):
        return self .next

    def set_next(self, n):
        self.next = n

class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add_node(self, item):
        tmp = Node(item)
        tmp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = tmp

    def search_item(self, item):
        current = self.head
        # current = Node(self.head)
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()
        return found
```

Comment: There is not inheritance your example. So what inheritance aspect are you not understanding? Could you change your question?

Comment: @olivecoder, correct, as I mentioned in my original post, I am not explicitly using inheritance or composition but somehow instead of declaring UnorderedList(Node) and then instantiating current = Node(self.head), simply doing current = self.head gives current access to Node's methods and I would like to understand why. Hope this clears up my question.

Comment: No TBadr. You are not using inheritance at all, explicitly or implicitly (?). The question doesn't have any relation with inheritance. You are only not being able to follow the code. I could say the concept here is composition not inheritance but that doesn't matter at all. So I tried so suggest an edit for your question but I couldn't imagine a title for that, definitively it is not the current.

Comment: Point taken, it might be some sort of implicit composition that I am not understanding, sorry if my post is confusing. Edited the title to change I inheritance to composition, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you comment out `add_node` then you do not add nodes to your linked list any longer therefore `search_item` will always see the initial value of `self.head` which is `None`.

Calling `current.get_next()` just works because via `add_node` you always ensure that `self.head` points either to `None` or to an instance of `Node` as `tmp` is created by `tmp = Node(item)` and then assigned to `self.head = tmp`. Therefore when setting `current = self.head` it will already refer to an instance of `Node` (or `None`) so you do not need to call `current = Node(self.head)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DAXaholic. I tested out your explanation by adding a third class in the file (Stack) and added a dummy method within the List class that point to a Stack instance. I wanted to see what "current" picks up if self.head points to more than one type of object. The odd thing is "current" always picks up the Node class methods and attributes only regardless of which order they are called and the only way it picks up the stack methods and attributes is if I comment out the code where self.head points to a Node object.

Comment: I ran further experiments by setting self.head to different types of objects within the class. What happens then is that if you set a certain var = self.head, then it will take on the type of the first object that it has been defined us (in my case a Node object via self.head = tmp) otherwise it remains NoneType. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently came across the concept of duck typing and this old post of mine came to mind. It seems that this is what's at play and just didn't understand it at the time. 'current' is set to None by default, by when invoking any of the methods defined in the Node class, it is automatically defined as Node object.